# how to add NixOS unstable channel declaratively in configuration.nix

Tags: nix, nixos

The NixOS cheatsheet describes how to install packages from `unstable` in `configuration.nix`.

It starts off by saying to add the unstable channel like so:

```
$ sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
$ sudo nix-channel --update
```

Then, it is easy to use this channel in `configuration.nix` (since it should now be on `NIX_PATH`):

```
nixpkgs.config = {
  allowUnfree = true;
  packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    unstable = import <nixos-unstable> {
      config = config.nixpkgs.config;
    };
  };
};

environment = {
  systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    unstable.google-chrome
  ];
};
```

---

I would like to not have to do the manual `nix-channel --add` and `nix-channel --update` steps.

I would like to be able to install my system from `configuration.nix` without first having to run the `nix-channel --add` and `nix-channel --update` steps.

Is there a way to automate this from `configuration.nix`?

Comment: Take a look at how `fetchTarball` is used here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733553/import-unstable-and-inherit-config You should be able to import nixos-unstable the same way.

Comment: Would you be able to add an answer explaining that?  I keep getting `infinite recursion encountered` errors when trying to do something like that.  The answer in that question doesn't seem to quite work.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Actually, after playing around with it a little more, I was able to get this working.  I'll add an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was able to get this working with a suggestion by @EmmanuelRosa.

Here are the relevant parts of my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
  unstableTarball =
    fetchTarball
      https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz;
in
{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      /etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix
    ];

  nixpkgs.config = {
    packageOverrides = pkgs: {
      unstable = import unstableTarball {
        config = config.nixpkgs.config;
      };
    };
  };

  ...
};
```

This adds an `unstable` derivative that can be used in `environment.systemPackages`.

Here is an example of using it to install the `htop` package from nixos-unstable:

```
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    ...
    unstable.htop
  ];
```

Comment: In a separate question, Robert Hensing explains how to replace entire nixos modules with those from unstable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842655/3040129

Comment: This solution works, I would just like to point out that in order to have a reproducible system you must pin both the stable channel and the unstable one inside the configuration, e.g. by using fetchFromGithub with the "rev" parameter

Comment: @DavidCosta if you posted an answer to this question showing how to do that, I would vote it up.  (And I'm sure it would be appreciated by people other than just me.)

Comment: I'm wondering if we can just do this in the `pkgs` argument itself. But I'm not sure how all the other arguments will work.

Comment: it's better to use `fetchTarball https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable/nixexprs.tar.xz`

Comment: @srghma Why is that?  Do you a link that explains the difference between the two?

Comment: @illabout, this is exactly what is used on your question - `sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable`. How did I know: I had the same url in my channel, then I added `unstableTarball = fetchTarball https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz;` and made  `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` and all my packages started to rebuild, but when I changed to `fetchTarball https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable/nixexprs.tar.xz` - `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` worked without rebuild

Comment: @srghma I imagine that is because https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz and https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable/nixexprs.tar.xz are different versions of unstable.  But that doesn't mean you should be using the one from nixos.org over the one from GitHub. In fact, it seems like most people pin the version of unstable by using something like `fetchFromGitHub`, instead of using `fetchTarball`.

Comment: pin packages and control via parameter (e.g. in environments) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124085/how-to-pin-an-import-nixpkgs-call-to-a-specific-commit/66720361#66720361