# How to find the commit a Nix channel points to?

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

When trying to revive old projects, sometimes I have to fish around for [older Nixpkgs commits](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commits/) to get things started.

For example, most of my `shell.nix` files start like this,

```hs
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.mkShell {
  # ...
}
```

that would import all expressions from the commit where the current [channel](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111201831/https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Channels) points to, but after some time, there have been so many changes that my project won't build anymore; then I will have to find a commit that still works, and go from there.

```
$ nix-shell --arg pkgs \
> 'import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/0c0fe6d85b92c4e992e314bd6f9943413af9a309.tar.gz") {}'
```

It would probably be the best if I could just save the working commit from the channel at the time, and have something solid to fall back to when needed later.

Answer (score 7):

`>= nixos 20.09`

```
nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m"
```

- system: `"x86_64-linux"`
- host os: `Linux 5.9.15, NixOS, 20.09.2344.a3a3dda3bac (Nightingale)` # channel-commit
- multi-user?: `yes`
- sandbox: `yes`
- version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.3.9`
- channels(root): `"nixos-20.09.2344.a3a3dda3bac"` # channel-commit
- channels(user): `"nixos-20.09.2152.e34208e1003"` # channel-commit
- nixpkgs: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos`

---

check the ending e.g. `a3a3dda3bac`
in the [NixOS history](https://channels.nix.gsc.io/) like [release 20.09](https://channels.nix.gsc.io/nixos-20.09/history-v2)

---

I would not use `pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}` for developing environments which are not tied to the current system you are running on

- instead import e.g. in `let` area via a variable

for developing environments:

```
# nix-shell shell_test.nix --argstr commitNixpkgs "0c0fe6d85b92c4e992e314bd6f9943413af9a309 --show-trace

{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {},  commitNixpkgs ? "0c0fe6d85b92c4e992e314bd6f9943413af9a309" ; ref ? "refs/heads/nixpkgs-unstable", rev ? "502845c3e31ef3de0e424f3fcb09217df2ce6df6" , ...}:

let 
    nixPkgs = import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/${commitNixpkgs}.tar.gz") {config= { allowUnfree = true ; } ;} ; 
    # https://channels.nix.gsc.io/
    # git ls-remote https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs | grep unstable
 
    # or via fetchGit 
    nixPkgs_fG = import (builtins.fetchGit {
       name = "nixpkgs-unstable";
       url = "https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs-channels.git";
       ref = ${ref};        #"refs/heads/nixpkgs-unstable";
       rev = ${rev};        #"502845c3e31ef3de0e424f3fcb09217df2ce6df6"; 
   }) {config= { allowUnfree = true ; } ;  } ;
   # nix-shell -p nix-prefetch-git --run ' nix-prefetch-git https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs.git refs/heads/nixos-unstable '

in 
  ...
```

Comment: This does not work for me:
```
 - system: `"aarch64-darwin"`
 - host os: `Darwin 21.6.0, macOS 12.6`
 - multi-user?: `yes`
 - sandbox: `no`
 - version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.11.0`
 - channels(sam.ainsworth): `"home-manager"`
 - channels(root): `"nixpkgs"`
 - nixpkgs: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixpkgs`
```

Comment: @skainswo What is the error when executing with code part?

Comment: @InLaw, no error, the output of nix-info just doesn't include the committish-level details. (I'm having the same experience; had query `lib.version` from `<nixpkgs>` directly).

Comment: This solution only applies to get the commit from the channel named 'nixos' as opposed to any channel name.

Answer (score 3):

To get the full Git revision, run `cat /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixpkgs/.git-revision; echo` (there's no newline at EOF, so we need to add one to avoid the prompt overwriting it). If that path doesn't exist you're probably using a different channel name, and need to specify it. Don't use a glob unless you're absolutely sure there's only ever one channel.

Then run `nix-prefetch-url --type sha256 --unpack "https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/archive/$(cat /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixpkgs/.git-revision).tar.gz"` to get the SHA-256 hash.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer provided in the NixOS discourse thread [How to see what commit is my channel on?](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-see-what-commit-is-my-channel-on/4818):

> **Note**: ***Before trying any of these methods, make sure that you are issuing commands with the right user!***
> No harm done either way, but if you are on NixOS and [manage things declaratively](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-package-management) (as `root` when rebuilding the system) then you might get a different commit hash than what you need. (Especially if you ever issued `nix-channel --update` without `sudo`, which will set up a channel for **your** user profile as well.)

#### Method 0

According to the [NixOS wiki's *Nix channels* entry](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Channels), "*a **channel** is a name for the latest "verified" git commits in [Nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs)*". That is, at any given time, a channel points to a specific commit in [the Nixpkgs git repository on Github](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs); **each Nix channel is actually a git branch in the repo**:

```
$ nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-20.09
-----                            ----------- 
(name)                          (branch-name)
#                                     |
#                                     V
#              https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/<branch-name>
#         i.e. https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/nixos-20.09
```

So if you just executed `nix-channel --update` before `nix-shell`, and it works, just look up the last commit in the channel branch in the [Nixpkgs repo](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs).

#### Method 1

["*Chapter 12. Channels*" of the Nix manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-channels) mentions that `nix-channel --update` "*makes the union of each channel’s Nix expressions available by default to `nix-env` operations (via the symlink `~/.nix-defexpr/channels`)*".

To see where the `~/.nix-defexpr/channels` symlink points to, use `readlink -f` to follow the symlink chain and combine it with `ls` to get straight to the point:

```
$ ls -l $(readlink -f ~/.nix-defexpr/channels)
total 6432
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root root      4096 Jan  1  1970 ./
drwxrwxr-t 8191 root nixbld 6569984 Feb  9 15:51 ../
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root        78 Jan  1  1970 nixos -> /nix/store/k737c631q19n54fhjmnf68frg5dar14w-nixos-20.09.3009.8e78c2cfbae/nixos/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root        60 Jan  1  1970 manifest.nix -> /nix/store/a5wl1fri2sasnsb1i5zscni5h7kjg7d6-env-manifest.nix
```

My channel's name is `nixos`, and it points to

```
/nix/store/k7..4w-nixos-20.09.3009.8e78c2cfbae/nixos/
                                   -----------
                                        ^
                                        |
                                   channel-commit
```

and the commit hash is right after the [MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH version number](https://semver.org/).

---

**Aside**: To construct the tarball URL for `fetchTarball` in the question, use the following template:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<full-or-abbr-commit-hash>.tar.gz
```

For example:

```
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/8e78c2cfbae.tar.gz
```

Alternatively, click the green "Code" button, and copy the URL of the "Download ZIP" link (and change the `zip` extension to `tar.gz`).

---

**Fun fact**: if you did `nix-channel --update` before method 1, then URLs `https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/<branch-name>` and `https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/<channel-commit>` will point to the same place in the [Nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) repo.

Comment: There are much easier ways to find the channel version.  You can use `nix-instantiate --eval -A 'lib.version' '<nixpkgs>'` or just start a `nix repl '<nixpkgs>'` and type `lib.version` at the prompt.  This will print something like `"20.09.3087.2394284537b"`.

Comment: @HenriMenke These are not the same (and to get the same commit as with `lib.version`, probably the shortest command would be `nixos-version`). Just did a `git show` on both, and the version commit hash is a month older than the one on my main channel. Plus, there could multiple channels. On the other hand, being a novice when it comes to Nix/NixOS/Nixpkgs, I'm quite sure that there must be a shorter method.

Comment: `nixos-version` only works on NixOS, obviously.  When you run `nix-instantiate --eval -A 'lib.version' '<nixpkgs>'` you get the commit that the `nixpkgs` channel is on.  If you have another channel, e.g. `nixpkgs-unstable` just use that between the angle brackets.  There should also be no mismatch between `lib.version` and the path in the Nix store: http://dpaste.com/BTN64D5SL (expires in 10 days)

Comment: About `nixos-version`: ; totally forgot that it is just on NixOS:) Thanks also for the one-liner (just learned another thing) but I still get different results on my end. Do you get the same results after you do `nix-channel --update`? Could this be a NixOS-specific thing?

Comment: On NixOS the situation is a bit more tricky because users can have different channels than the system.  Alas, I can't say much about that because I'm using flakes to get around the headache that channels are.  You can check whether the `pkgs.path` attribute points to the same directory as the `~/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixpkgs` symlink, i.e. `nix-instantiate --eval -A 'pkgs.path' '<nixpkgs>'`. Example: http://dpaste.com/339BV4UN2 (expires in 10 days)